# NestJS, защита от одновременных запросов

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Пишу приложение на NestJS с использованием typeorm. Возник вопрос который не могу решить. Если сделать 2 одинаковых http запроса, которые обновляют базу данных, и если эти запросы будут одновременные, то данные в базе данных будут изменены 2 раза, из-за чего что-то может сломаться, или пользователь может получить то, что ему не надо.

Есть ли возможность блокировать строку в базе данных во время запроса пользователя, или хотя бы запретить 2 одинаковых одновременных запроса от пользователя?

Comment: На клиенте кнопку вырубайте. На сервере не принимайте запрос, если текущий еще выполняется. Организуйте очередь запросов. Потом поймите, запись в БД будет последовательной. Если заблокировать строку, второй запрос встанет в очередь и будет ждать разблокировки строки и как она разблокируется, все равно выполнится. Блокировкой строки в БД можно уронить все приложение )

Comment: А можно ли как-то организовать запрос, который будет проверять равно ли старое значение старому, или уже поменялось? Точнее не можно ли, а делается ли это автоматически, или обязательно писать вручную

Comment: Да кто же его знает, можно так сделать или нет, если не понятно что вы хотите проверять, где и зачем ) Нужен конкретный пример, желательно с минимально достаточным набором кода, что бы понять, как это работает сейчас и как должно.

Comment: typeorm при вызове метода save сама проверяет в полях "равно ли старое значение старому, или уже поменялось" и в случае если поменялось - делает update. И при вызове .update, емнип, тоже.

Comment: если вам так уж важно решать эту задачу, решайте её максимально просто, например, добавьте поле version_id и не сохраняйте если version_id в БД не совпадает с dto.version_id, ну и в момент сохранения инкрементируйте